# Windows SDK Version was not found

Tags: visual-studio, driver, kmdf

On my Windows 7 machine, I have both the Windows SDK(10.0.14393.795) and WDK(10.0.14393.0) versions, yet, when I am building our project in Visual Studio 2015, it keeps on saying that

MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".

The options I have when I am retargeting the solutions are 10.0.10240 and 8.1 but not 10.0.14393.

How can I build this correclty?